# check Primary key in sqldf package

Tags: sqldf, rstudio-server, rsqlite

While creating a database using the sqldf package, I created a table named Company Master. I want to link it to different tables but before doing that i wanted to check if the format is correct it or not. In MySQL it tells immediately  if the format is correct or not when enter is pressed. Is there any way in rstudio to do the same before proceeding so as to not come back if the process has gone wrong.

```
library(sqldf)
first <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname= "DATA.sqlite")

dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
            "CREATE TABLE COMPANY MASTER
            ( 
CompId INTEGER,
CompName TEXT,
Address TEXT,
DirectorName TEXT,
EmployeeNo INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(CompName)
            )")
```

Comment: This code is not using the sqldf package.